# How to select a row in the react virtualized Grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

In one of my projects, I am using the React Virtualized Grid. One of the requirements is to select a row whenever the user clicks on it. In other words, I want to highlight that complete row as it has large number of records and I don't want to lose the track.
What is the way in the React Virtualized Grid to highlight the complete row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cellRenderer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrenderer) prop to customise the row rendering and `onClick` of row you can highlight that particular row.

Comment: I have used the cellRenderer for this. How to add the event listener so that whenever the user clicks on the cell respective row should get selected/highlighted.